# Визуальное исправление для DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net

Вывожу данные из БД в DataGridView, однако в БД длинная строка занимает порядка 200 символов, а в строке столько не влазит. Из-за этого в DataGrid появляется многоточие (см. скриншот).

[image]

Каким образом его можно убрать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите свойство AutoSizeRowMode в AllCells (если Вам нужно чтобы была видна вся строка), а в DefaultCellStyle свойство WrapMode в True.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не совсем, что мне было нужно, но когда попробовал, то этот вариант оказался даже лучше!

Answer (score 2):

А зачем Вам в БД строки фиксированной длины?

Comment: Признаться честно - имею небольшой опыт проектирования БД. Однако, как мне кажется - это более удобно и безопасно с точки зрения вывода данных на форму.